# Node/Expressjs 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present' Twitter API

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, twitter, express

I'm using Node with Express with the twit and express-cors modules for a Twitter API app.

I got everything working with jQuery and I'm now trying to get it working with vanilla JS.

I get the console message "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.jsonq=%23cats&callback=?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404."

This happens both with and without the callback parameter.

So here is the relevant Node code:

```
var express = require('express'),
cors = require('express-cors'),
Twit = require('twit'),
path = require('path');

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         ''
  , consumer_secret:      ''
  , access_token:         ''
  , access_token_secret:  ''
})    

var app = express();

app.use(cors({
    allowedOrigins: [
        'twitter.com'
    ]
}))

app.get('/api/search/:hashtag', function(req, res){ 

    T.get('search/tweets', { q: '#cats', count: 5 }, function(err, data, response) {
      res.jsonp(data); // jsonp or json, neither seem to work
      console.log(data)
    });
});

app.param('hashtag', function(req, res, next, hashtag){
    req.hashtag = hashtag;
    next();
});
```

The AJAX call is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", function(){ getCORS(url, success); });

  function getCORS(url, success) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.onload = success;
      xhr.send();
      return xhr;
  }

  getCORS('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.jsonq=%23cats', function(request){
      response = request.currentTarget.response || request.target.responseText;
      console.log(response);
  });
```

It was working with the jQuery version without the express-cors module even. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post the jQuery version that was working?

Comment: Sure @Andrew Lavers. In the HTML file: 

`´$('#submitButton').click(function(e){
              $.get('/api/search/' + $('#hashtag').val(), function(data){
                console.log('data', data);

                ...

                }

              });
              e.preventDefault();
            });`

Comment: In Node:

`var express = require('express'),
Twit = require('twit'),
path = require('path');

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         ''
  , consumer_secret:      ''
  , access_token:         ''
  , access_token_secret:  ''
})    

var app = express();

app.get('/api/search/:hashtag', function(req, res){ 

    T.get('search/tweets', { q: '#cats', count: 5 }, function(err, data, response) {
      res.json(data); 
      console.log(data)
    });
});

app.param('hashtag', function(req, res, next, hashtag){
    req.hashtag = hashtag;
    next();
});`

Comment: You know you can edit your question with these code snippets instead of trying to cram them into the comment field...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mounting the cors middleware twice. See if getting rid of the first `app.use(cors())` fixes it. Then you can try using curl to test it out. `curl -v -H "Origin: https://twitter.com" http://localhost:3000/` replacing the port 3000 with the port you're using.

Comment: Oops I was! It didn't fix the issue though. I've tested with curl, got this response: `curl -v -H "Origin: https://twitter.com" http://localhost:3000/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused"`